# C# action block await doesnt work as expected

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

The Problem seemed to be with await firing before some async blocks where completed.
Either because I did something, the objects do not support or more likely, i screwed somewhere up. But since the Problem needed to much code to occur, it was considered a code dump =(

I hope this helps, a little bit.

I ditched the Broadcastblock and switched to a task based pipeline.

using the task factory for crawler that needs to have write access to its own input:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx

solved the problems.

The sync version of these are ideal for slow producers/fast consumers

taskfactory -> create your tasks, and connect them via a BlockingCollection,
sadly you cant have a foreach consuming enumerable with a last flag (would be nice for a crawler as this)

Comment: There's way too much code in this question, and yet at the same time you haven't provided a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Please improve this question.

Comment: I thought I did, i will rewrite the code on Tuesday.
Are there any specifics, you need? 
I thought giving you the context of the action block and the action block would suffice.

Comment: The words "complete" and "minimal" are in the phrase [mcve] for a reason. It is not sufficient to provide "context", nor is it sufficient to just dump your code here. You need to _craft_ a code example tailor-made to your question. It needs to be able to be compiled and run with no added code, and it needs to contain _nothing_ except the bare _minimum_ code required to reproduce the problem. Please read [mcve] for more details.

Comment: I will, I thought my Problem was a simple one. That is why i dumped it here.

Comment: I think you forgot to make this async: `private static Task merge(Func<ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>> getter, Action<ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>> setter, List<parserPart>list)` should be  `private static async Task merge(Func<ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>> getter, Action<ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>> setter, List<parserPart>list)`

Comment: @Spluf If i have it async ( compare with previous version), the compiler complains about it not having an await inside. Which it does not have.

Comment: and that's exactly what it should do, now you just have to tell it what to await. You need to decorate your method with async in order to await it's results. Also, if it is async but you are not awaiting anything it will still run synchroniously, so, in your case, you should probably `await setter(target);` or `await Task.FromResult(setter(target));`

Comment: @Spluf Thank you, for your input. It led me to a way to await for sync.
await Task.Run(() => setter(target));
But the ActionBlock and the Task, are still not awaited.
Any ideas, what I am still doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, try replacing your merge method with this:

```
 private static async Task merge(Func<ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>> getter, Action<ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>> setter, List<parserPart>list)
        {
            List<Task> tasks  = new List<Task>();
            var target = getter();
            int buffer;
            foreach (parserPart b in list)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
                    target.TryGetValue(b.uploader_id, out buffer);
                    target.TryAdd(b.uploader_id, (buffer + b.count));
                }
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); 
            await Task.Run(() => setter(target));
            Console.Writeline("merging task");
        }
    }
```

also, use  the Complete method before awaiting for Completion:

```
splitter.Complete();
sorter.Complete();
await Task.WhenAll(svn, splitter.Completion, sorter.Completion);
```

P.S. .. I haven't tested this since it's too much code to replicate but you did say that your merge method keeps running after you get some of the results, so, by creating that list of  tasks, you can wait for the entire list to finish before getting the results.

Comment: thank you! i will test it on the 13. I have currently no access to my code nor VS. I will let you know about the results.

Comment: Your Idea fixed the Problem in part, the merge function now only outputs 2 messages after the program returns to main.
I will upload a new version of the question soon, this time hopefully simple enough =)

Comment: This did not completly solved the Problem, but Spluf was the only one who tried, and his answer led me to the pinpointing the problem to the merge / broadcaster blocks of my original code

Answer (score 0):

The Complete method will do what you need I believe. Documentation here has a good example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194731%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The method would stop the accepting of data, but does not return an awaitable task, as in, when all data is processed is completed.It simply blocks any new data. wich i want to process